# Twoway summary statistics table for continuous variables

Tags: stata

What is the best way to create a twoway summary statistics table for continuous tables? e.g. a table that looks like

```
           Group1           Group2          Total
      mean       sd      mean      sd     mean     sd
x1      1         2       3         4       5       6 
x2      7         7       7         7       7       7
```

`summarize` does this easily but without the groupings.

I have also looked at `tabulate` and `tabout`, but those seem more relevant when x1 and x2 are discrete variables.

It would also be good if the table can be exported as a LaTeX file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not really an out-of-the box solution for this. There used to be `latabstat`, but I found this not very comfortable to work with. When I am faced with such a task, I usually do it by hand:

```
log using table.tex, text replace
log on
foreach v in x1 x2 {
    di "`v' " _c 
    foreach gr in Group1 Group2 {
        qui sum `v' if `gr' == 1
        di " & " r(mean) " & " r(sd) _c
    }
    ** Total Group
    qui sum `v' 
     di " & " r(mean) " & " r(sd) " \\"
}
log off
```

This way, you have the body of your table right in the logfile, which can be included in the Latex Document

Answer (score 0):

Collapse can give you want you want. You just need to make sure the data is organized properly.

You should have one variable for your "x"'s. Then you just need the data you want summarized as an individual variable for group1, group2, and total, respectively. You need to duplicate these variables to have multiple summary statistics, but then collapse can just, well, collapse the data into a table of summary stats.

```
    clear

    * Generate Data
    set obs 20
    gen x = "x1" in 1/10
    replace x = "x2" in 11/20
    set seed 122
    gen m_group1 = runiform()
        gen sd_group1 = m_group1    // Duplicate data for SD column
    gen m_group2 = runiform()
        gen sd_group2 = m_group2
    gen m_total = m_group1 + m_group2
        gen sd_total = m_total

    collapse    (mean) m_group1 (sd) sd_group1  /// Group 1
                (mean) m_group2 (sd) sd_group2  /// Group 2
                (mean) m_total (sd) sd_total    /// Total Group
                , by(x)
```